# How can I read barcodes from an external barcode scanner plugged into the USB Host port of my BeagleBone Black?

Tags: python, embedded, beagleboneblack

I have a barcode scanner module that I've connected to my BBB's USB Host port.
I've determined that the scanner is tied to /dev/input/event1.

However, instead of returning the barcode string like it does when plugged into my laptop, i.e:
"780060850524" -- It returns a bunch of characters I can't interpret.

I do 'sudo cat event1' and scan a barcode, this returns:
[image]

[image]

I can't figure out how to interpret the barcode string from the data. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the right way, I'm not very experienced. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: If you could dump the output as hex bytes, you might have a better chance of decoding it.

Comment: Do not post _pictures_ of _text_, whether that is _code_ or console output.  Model/manufacturer of the scanner would be useful.

Comment: Using `od -tx1z` is always better than `cat` when trying to understand unknown data. Also, if you want help do not post screen grabs. Copy paste the text into your question. That includes your Python code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you use the bar code scanner on your laptop, are you running Linux on the laptop and accessing it the same way? Do you have a driver installed perchance on the laptop that isn't on the BBB?